# how to deactivate and activate users from application in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, dashboard

I am implementing dashboard facility in my ruby on rails application  where only Admin can enter and see all users which are registered with application. From dashboard, admin can deactivate or activate users( may be for certain time of period). I have User table which has is_active column. I know , it can be done by setting flag on this column in table. Could you please explain it in details.

Following is my User table.

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.boolean  "is_admin"
    t.boolean  "is_active"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.string   "username"
  end
```

Please help me in implementing activation and deactivation of users from application(Admin can only this)

Answer (score 1):

you can create two method in `User` model for activating & deactivating user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 def activate_account!
   update_attribute :is_active, true
 end

 def deactivate_account!
   update_attribute :is_active, false
 end
end
```

As type of `is_active` column is boolean, you can use `user.is_active?` method generated by rails to check if user's account is active or not

Answer (score 0):

For you, I suggest looking into CanCan or another authorization gem. There isn't anything you can do in the migration, which you provided, about this so I suggest you check out this screen-cast about implementing cancan.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have dashboard page where I have put Check box control to activate or deactivate users. I want If i click that check box, user should be deactivate for certain period of time. Is this no possible using devise only. Please let me know, if possible please explain it. Thanks

Comment: Devise provides authentication. This lets you know who is using your app. CanCan provides Authorization, this specifies what parts of your app a user has the ability to read or write.